# How do two ternary operators work together in JS?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

So I was doing a code problem online and one of the solutions showed the following

```
function electionsWinners(votes, k) {
  var max=Math.max(...votes)
  var r=votes.filter(x=>x+k>max||x===max).length
  return k?r:r==1?1:0
}
```

I don't think the specifics of the problem are relevant, I'm more interested in how the return statement works. I don't understand at all what gets returned, it seems that 2 ternary operators are being used but I'm not sure, can anyone help me understand how exactly this return statement functions?

Comment: `k ? (r) : (r==1 ? (1) : (0))` afaic.

Comment: In general, try to avoid nested ternaries. They're inherently confusing. About the only time they're useful is in code golf, where you're being judged on terseness.

Comment: @Wendelin There's not really any other choice…

Comment: @Bergi , then what is the question?

Comment: The question is why do folks keep using more than one at a line.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at

```
k?r:r==1?1:0
```

as a single expression. Each `?` is connected to its immediately following `:`, so it's equivalent to:

```
k ? r : (r==1 ? 1 : 0)
```

where the second conditional operator takes effect only if the `k` is falsey. In that second conditional, if `r` is `1`, `1` is returned, else `0` is returned.

Might be clearer with indentation:

```
return (k
  ? r
  : (r == 1
    ? 1
    : 0
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes 2 ternary operators
return k?r:r==1?1:0

i will put the code with complete IF

```
if(k) //not is null
  return r;
else
{
  if(r==1)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert it to if else statement then you'll better understand what's going on:

```js
if (k) {
  return r;
} else if (r === 1) {
  return 1;
} else {
  return 0;
}
```

Or

```js
if (k) {
  return r;
}
if (r === 1) {
  return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first test is `k ?` is k not 0/undefined/null? If so, return r `(r)` else `:` if r is 1 `(r==1 ?)` return 1 `(1)` otherwise return 0 `(0))`